# Run scripts based on time of day

Tags: scripts, kubuntu, themes, plasma

I'd like to run a script based on the time of day, specifically so I can make my computer (Kubuntu 16.04) switch themes at night and day automatically based on the time. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945669/linux-how-to-run-script-at-certain-time

Comment: Look into `cron` and `at` . These two tools are ideal for scheduling tasks. Imho  `at` is better suited for GUI tasks. You could also write an autostart entry ,but that would require modification to the script , so that ot polls the time of day

Comment: What I really need is a way to test for the time every so often (10-15 minutes is fine) and if it's after 9 PM (or whatever), switch to the "breeze-dark" theme, else switch/stay on the "breeze" theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Kubuntu perhaps the *easiest* option is to use the gui task scheduler to run your script:

```
K-Button --> System Settings --> System Administration --> Task Scheduler
```

Select 'New Task' and then simply follow the menus through:

[image]

Comment: This looks really good, and I had to actually install it (it wasn't on there by default). However, I'm really not sure how to write the script itself. I've figured out how to get it to run a command every 15 minutes (so maybe it checks every 15 minutes for the time, and if it's after 9 PM it changes the theme). I understand if then commands, but I'm not sure how to change the theme from breeze to breeze dark with a command.

Comment: OIC, looks like I have answered part of your question only. Perhaps open a new question asking for guidance on the script itself and refer to this question?